# Django: how to get format date in views?

Tags: python, django, date

I need to use SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT in view.

```
def manage_list(request):

    user = User.objects.filter().order_by('date_joined') 
    usrs = [] 
    for usr in user: 
        usrs.append({
            _('First name'):  usr.first_name, 
            _('Last name'):   usr.last_name,
            _('Email'):       usr.email,
            _('Active'):      usr.is_active,
            _('Superuser'):   usr.is_superuser,
            _('Staff'):       usr.is_staff,
            _('Joined date'): usr.date_joined.strftime(SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT),    
        }) 

    data = simplejson.dumps(usrs, indent=4)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

usr.date_joined has a type of "date field" I think. I want to format this data according to django locale. so this string probably should help. I know that there's a template filter which does that I wan, but I want to format usr.date_joined **in view only** - saving django choosen locale.

If there's any other methods to do this please provide examples. in the end I just wanna have a formated date according to django locale which shows only date and time, I think this constant should do what the name says..

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `django.utils.formats` module is what you're looking for. The only reference I could find in the docs was in the [Django 1.2 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#date-format-helper-functions).

Remember that the localisation will only work if the [`USE_L10N`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n) setting is `True`. You can use the date_format as follows.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import formats
date_joined = datetime.now()
formatted_datetime = formats.date_format(date_joined, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT")
```

Comment: `from django.utils import formats` is the same? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#date-format-helper-functions maybe somebody will find usefull this. Thnx Alasdair! =)

Comment: Oops. That was a typo. `memset.utils` is one of my company's internal modules! The correct module is `django.utils`.

Comment: What's wrong with `from django.conf import settings` and then `settings.SHORT_DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: I understood that to mean that the value returned from `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` will be the locale specific one.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid the post is nearly 18 months old. I've removed the first version because it doesn't work with Django 1.4.X that I'm running on this machine. The remaining solution isn't made any shorter by importing `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` from settings.

Comment: I just realized the date of the post!

Answer (score 27):

You might want to try using django.utils.dateformat.DateFormat

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> from django.utils.dateformat import DateFormat
>>> from django.utils.formats import get_format
>>> df = DateFormat(dt)
>>> df.format(get_format('DATE_FORMAT'))
u'April 23, 2013'
>>> df.format('Y-m-d')
u'2013-04-23'
```

More information using Python:

```
import django
help(django.utils.dateformat)
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'django.utils' has no attribute 'dateformat'

Answer (score 13):

To use the Django **date** filter in a view use `defaultfilters`, e.g.:

```
from django.template import defaultfilters

formatted_date = defaultfilters.date(usr.date_joined, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT")
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `localize` shortcut.

```
>>> from django.utils.formats import localize
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> print(datetime.now())
2016-12-18 19:30:35.786818
>>> print(localize(datetime.now()))
18 декабря 2016 г. 19:30
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.utils.formats import date_format

date_format(usr.date_joined)
```

Comment: This does not add anything to existing answers. `date_format` was already suggested.

Comment: True, I noticed only after answering. But still, my answer is cleaner than the one given by Alasdair.

Answer (score 1):

As of today what worked for me was setting **USE_L10N** to **True**.

Then import some utils :

```
from django.utils import (dateformat, formats)
```

Which can be used as such :

```
dateformat.format(my_date_object, formats.get_format('DATE_FORMAT'))
```

Note thate `my_date_object` should be a datetime object.

And there is a list of available formats :

- DECIMAL_SEPARATOR
- THOUSAND_SEPARATOR
- NUMBER_GROUPING
- FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK
- MONTH_DAY_FORMAT
- TIME_FORMAT
- DATE_FORMAT
- DATETIME_FORMAT
- SHORT_DATE_FORMAT
- SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT
- YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT
- DATE_INPUT_FORMATS
- TIME_INPUT_FORMATS
- DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS

The name is pretty self explanatory...

see : https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/utils/formats.py