# How to convert a string into a localised date in django

Tags: python, django, date, localization, date-format

We are doing an AJAX call in Django, where a user enters a date and a number, and the AJAX call looks up if there already is a document with that number and date.

The application is internationalised and localised. The problem is how to interpret the date sent by AJAX into a valid Python/Django date object. This has to be done using the current users locale, ofcourse.

One solution I found does not work:
[Django: how to get format date in views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287883/django-how-to-get-format-date-in-views)
`get_format()` returns a string (in our case `j-n-Y`), but `strftime()` expects a format string in the form of `%j-%n-%Y`.

Why the Django format is different from the `stftime()` format beats me, FYI we're using Django 1.5 currently.

I think the problem is that in all examples I could find, the dates are already date objects, and Python/Django just does formatting. What we need is to convert the string into a date using the current locale, and THEN format it. I was figuring this would be a standard problem, but all of the possible solutions I found and tried don't seem to work...

Thanks,
Erik

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you include examples of strings you want to parse.

Comment: Ah, well, for example, today's date 07-03-2013 (Dutch format). I'd like to turn that into a date object, taking into account that the current locale is Dutch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitting a ticket to Django gave me a clue to the answer.
You can convert a specific type of data into an object by passing it through the corresponding field and calling to_python(). In my case with a date it would be like so:

```
from django.forms.fields import DateField

field = DateField()
value = request.GET.get('date', '')
formatted_datetime = field.to_python(value)
```

Erik

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me it would make your life easier to let the user select the date from a calendar, instead of typing its string representation.
This way you know exactly what you're getting.

Comment: I concur. I would probably add some client-side input masking as well.

Comment: We use a datepicker, jQueryUI's datepicker. This doesn't solve the problem, the datepicker is used in a Dutch browser, thus it returns Dutch formatted dates to the form. The problem is on the server-side where Django needs to interpret this date(string) into a proper date(object).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format, then you should be able to use `datetime.strptime` .

Have used it in code successfully in conjunction with ajax calls.

See here for more information: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Sorry legrisdev, In my original post I used stftime(), but I meant strptime(). The problem is that Django's get_format() returns j-n-Y and that strptime expects %j-%n-%Y. I can ofcourse use some string replacements to fix this, but it seems to me this problem sould be not uncommon and there is an easier way.