# Formating django to proper format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, datetime

I am getting data through Django api into my web application and the date return is **"2015-09-10T00:00:00Z"**, is there a javscript function that can turn this into format like **2015-09-10**

Comment: you could format it server side, this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287883/django-how-to-get-format-date-in-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = new Date("2015-09-10T00:00:00Z");
var result = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
```

This is cumbersome and error prone, also it removes the leading `0` for the month and day. Take a look at this js library: [mement.js](http://momentjs.com/), it should provide whatever you need to manipulate the time.
It's very light weight and easy to use.

Comment: is there any javascript function because for one single task i dont wanna include whole library

Comment: I updated my answer, but I still suggest using the library because, well, the library exists for a reason, there's no built in javascript function that handles this well. It's also light weight so there's no overhead. Check this answer to see how painful it is to manipulate the string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date